# Al seleccionar el tercer dato del Spinner se me cierra la Activity correspondiente al Spinner

Tags: java, android

Se cierra la ventana donde se encuentra el Spinner cuando selecciono la tercera opción del Spinner, con la primera y la segunda no hay problemas...

Este es el error en el Logcat

```
05-03 00:57:29.436 11301-11301/? E/AndroidRuntime:   
FATAL EXCEPTION: main Process:  com.example.matias.finalcode, PID: 11301
   java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: length=2; index=2
       at com.example.matias.finalcode.SignupActivityEmpresa.onItemSelected(SignupActivityEmpresa.java:199)
       at android.widget.AdapterView.fireOnSelected(AdapterView.java:897)
       at android.widget.AdapterView.access$200(AdapterView.java:48)
       at android.widget.AdapterView$SelectionNotifier.run(AdapterView.java:865)
       at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
       at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
       at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5258)
       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:898)
       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:693)
05-03 00:57:29.437 788-1622/? W/ActivityManager:   Force finishing activity com.example.matias.finalcode/.SignupActivityEmpresa
```

Y este es el código al que hace referencia en el error

```
@Override
    public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {

        int[] localidades = {R.array.array_sevilla, R.array.array_malaga};

        ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(
                this,
                localidades[i],
                android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);

        adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
        spinnerLoc.setAdapter(adapter);

        provincia = adapterView.getItemAtPosition(i).toString();

    }
```

Los array en el archivo string.xml son los siguientes

```
<string-array name="array_provincias">
        <item>Selecciona un país</item>
        <item>Sevilla</item>
        <item>Malaga</item>
    </string-array>

    <string-array name="array_sevilla">
        <item>Selecciona una ciudad</item>
        <item>Tomares</item>
        <item>Camas</item>
    </string-array>

    <string-array name="array_malaga">
        <item>Selecciona una ciudad</item>
        <item>Casares</item>
        <item>Estepona</item>
    </string-array>
```

De aquí saco el valor de [i] al pasarselo al onItemSelected...

```
ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(
                this,
                R.array.array_provincias,
                android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
        adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
        spinnerPro.setAdapter(adapter);
        spinnerPro.setOnItemSelectedListener(this);
```

¿Qué puede ser?, no sé cuál es el error.

Gracias por su tiempo!

Comment: Ese error suele darse cuando intentas acceder a una posición mayor de la que tiene tu array. Ej: `String[5]` e intentas acceder a la posición nº 5, te dará error.

Comment: @rencinas y cuál podría ser una posible solución?

Comment: De donde recoges el valor de `[i]`? al pasarselo al `onItemSelected`

Comment: @rencinas arriba agregue el código de donde saco el valor de [i]

Answer (score 4):

Te recomiendo hacer debug y verificar que valor tiene el parametro `[i]` ya que por lo que salta el error, estés pasando valor `2` y el array es de 2 posiciones. `[0] y [1]`

A groso modo algo que podrías hacer, es restarle a la `[i]` una unidad cuando recibes el parámetro.

```
@Override
    public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {
    i = i-1;//Reducimos en 1 el valor que tiene i para evitar el error
    int[] localidades = {R.array.array_sevilla, R.array.array_malaga};

    ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(
            this,
            localidades[i],
            android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);

    adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
    spinnerLoc.setAdapter(adapter);

    provincia = adapterView.getItemAtPosition(i).toString();

}
```

Con eso se debería solucionar tu problema.

Comment: claro, `array_provincias` tiene 3 indices, pero el indice 0 no corresponde a nada

Comment: @Klaimmore sí, tienes razón. Agregué otro valor y así se solucionó. Gracias!

Comment: @rencinas Gracias también por tu ayuda, de hecho con tus comentarios pude solucionar el problema.